# "Neo.ClientError.Statement.ExternalResourceFailed" and then placed in Import folder and still no output

Tags: csv, neo4j, load

S1. Entered the script got error as above

S2. [enter image description here]
[image]
[image]
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/dTHuh.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7pEfx.png)enter image description here

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MT7DE.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gwtQD.png)

The file was executed but no nodes or relationships were created and the output came as "(no changes, no records)"

Comment: pls give us your script and some sample data. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

can you return the rows from csv file and check if there are rows present?

`LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///saphitechifregv1.csv" as line RETURN line`

and then check if your where condition matches!

Thanks!